# React / Sentry for Error Reporting - How to not send errors from dev / localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry

We're using Sentry in our React project by adding the following to our main `index.js` and `App.js` files:

**index.js**

```
// Import Stuff
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react';
import { Integrations } from '@sentry/tracing';
... import other important react stuff...

// https://sentry.io/onboarding/cbb-analytics/get-started/ (not my real dsn)
Sentry.init({
    dsn: 'https://asdkfa930209jcdzkljaasdfasdf@o123456.ingest.sentry.io/3293942',
    integrations: [
        new Integrations.BrowserTracing()
    ],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react';
... other imports for app.js ...

// And Create The App
function App() {
    // check logged in...
    // check global state...
    // fetch some global data...

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={globalStateObj}>
            <AppNavbar />
            <LoginModal />
            <Sentry.ErrorBoundary fallback={ErrorBoundaryFallback}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <HomePage {...props} />}
                    <Route exact path='/about-us' component={AboutUs} />
                    <Route exact path='/reports' component={Reports} />
                    <Route component={NoMatch} />
                </Switch>
            </Sentry.ErrorBoundary>

            <AppFooter />
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

We could certainly be more granular with our Error Boundaries, but as it stands, wrapping the whole `switch`, which contains 99% of the code in our app, is getting the job done for us. Whenever a user runs into any issue on the website, we're getting that as an issue in Sentry.

However, we would prefer it if Issues weren't created in Sentry if the error comes from dev / localhost... We break stuff / get errors all the time in dev when writing new code, and sending these as issues to Sentry just clutters Sentry and makes it a bit harder to keep track of those important errors that happen in production.

Can we use our `process.env.NODE_ENV` to determine dev vs prod, and use this somewhere in `index.js` or in `App.js` to prevent issues from being sent for localhost? Or perhaps sentry has a way to explicitly ignore issues from an ip, like `localhost:3000`?

Answer (score 31):

Set `enabled` in the Sentry config to false when not in production.

```
Sentry.init({
    dsn: 'your-dsn',
    integrations: [
        new Integrations.BrowserTracing()
    ],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0, // Should not use 1.0 in production
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
});
```

Side note: Sentry [discourages setting `tracesSampleRate` to 1.0 in production](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/configuration/sampling/#sampling-transaction-events)

Comment: Note in 2023 I had to use `enable_tracing=` instead of `enabled=`, for the Python package

Answer (score 24):

#### *2023-July Answer*

Try looking for `Inbound Filter` inside `Project Settings` in Sentry.

It has an option to filter-out localhost.

This doesn't count against quotas as well.

[image: Inbound Data Filter Option in Sentry]

Comment: Is this based on the IP address or the URL? Because the errors show the real IP address, while only the URL field has `127.0.0.1` embedded in it.

Comment: Looks like it is based on the URL. It has already begun filtering out the events from our developers' local environments. Thanks! :)

Comment: Can't believe this is not set as a default; probably a way to hike up events to hit the quota and make money!

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way I could get it working was to set the beforeSend method in Sentry.init to return null if the location is localhost.

```js
Sentry.init({
  dsn:
    'your dsn here',
  integrations: [new Integrations.BrowserTracing()],
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0

  beforeSend: (event) => {
    if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost') {
      return null;
    }
    return event;
  },
});
```

Comment: I like this option since this will also allow us to print (stdout/stderr) messages in development vs production

Comment: Perhaps Try looking for `Inbound Filter` inside Project Settings in Sentry. It does the same and doesn't count against quotas as well.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to know you're on dev using location or with some dev-env or with process.env or .env file... nevermind

```
function onDev() {
  return window.location.href.startsWith('http://localhost');
}
```

then create a Wrapper like

```
function SentryNoDev({ErrorBoundaryFallback, children}) {
   return onDev()
   ? children
   : <Sentry.ErrorBoundary fallback={ErrorBoundaryFallback}>{children}</Sentry.ErrorBoundary>
   ;
}
```

Comment: I guess it really can be this simple. I'll give this a shot, although I don't see why it wouldn't work. Thanks

Comment: So this doesn't work. Interestingly, I removed the `Sentry.ErrorBoundary` all-together, and yet I am still getting issues sent to Sentry. So the `Sentry.ErrorBoundary` only handles error handling, whereas the `Sentry.init` is what I really need to handle...

Comment: per https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/574, it looks like setting the `DSN` to null is the way to go...

Comment: Unfortunately with this implementation, you don't see the error boundary when getting errors when running locally. I've posted a solution that preserves the error boundary.

Answer (score 1):

In Create-React-App

```js
// index.js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  Sentry.init({...});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- I don't recommend you put your dsn in the code i would suggest you set it to an env variable for example REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN
- wherever you supply your env variable you can put your dsn there
- if you supply the env variables through netlify for example the REACT_APP_ENV for staging be 'staging' for production 'production'  then

```
let shouldSendToSentry = 
  ['staging','production'].includes(process.env.REACT_APP_ENV)
```

2 ways from here

- wrap your sentry config in an if condition
  for example:

```
if(shouldSendToSentry ){
  sentry.init({
    dsn: process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN
  })
}
```

- the other way is by

```
beforeSend: (event) => {
    if (!shouldSendToSentry) {
      return null;
    }
return event;
```

which in this case it will ignore all issues coming from any other environments

resources:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuFEsUGK93g
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1Gm_K4Ux0s
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGgoP6HDR-I
- https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/

Comment: putting the `dsn` into code doesnt matter. its just as public as in your `.env` file on the client

Answer (score 0):

https://ngrok.com/ is a good solution in case localhost filter can't be changed.